Why can't record struct contain init property?
This is my C# code:
record struct recName(int A) { }
And this is generated code behind the scenes:
internal struct recName : IEquatable<recName>
{
    public recName(int A)
    {
        <A>k__BackingField = A;
    }

    private int <A>k__BackingField;
    public int A
    {
        get { return <A>k__BackingField; }
        set { <A>k__BackingField = value; }
    }
}

Why structs properties generated with get/set properties, but type declared with same syntax like this is generated as a 'get/init'. record class recName(int A) { }:
internal class recName : IEquatable<recName>
{
    public recName(int A)
    {
        <A>k__BackingField = A;
    }

    private readonly int <A>k__BackingField;
    public int A
    {
        get
        {
            return <A>k__BackingField;
        }
        init
        {
            <A>k__BackingField = value;
        }
    }
}

I cant understand why 'record struct' cant contain get/init property?

Record structs can contain get/init properties. You can try declaring one yourself. It's just that the parameters in the primary constructor does not generate get/init properties, but get/set properties instead. If you want to ask why they don't generate get/init properties, please clarify what kind of answer you want first.

Short answer, this is by design: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record#immutability Use readonly record struct if you want the read-only behavior in your record struct.

Also, note that the parameters in the primary constructor does generate get/init properties for a readonly record struct.
